# Python sqlalchemy Filtrar por valores maximos

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

La idea del proyecto es simular un torneo por lo que se generan 8 valores aleatorios que representan la puntuación de la primera ronda, la intención es filtrar los 4 valores mas altos para generar solo los valores de la segunda ronda de las 4 personas que pasaron, pero aunque a veces si funciona y solo modifica esos valores hay otras ocasiones en las que modifica mas valores o incluso todos, este proyecto se esta haciendo en una base de datos tratando de hacerse en una aplicación online con flask, por favor tener en cuenta eso, les muestro el código de la fase 2:

```
@app.route('/fase-2')
def segunda():
todo_el_torneo = db.session.query(Torneo)
lista = []
for x in todo_el_torneo:
    lista.append(x.puntaje1)
lista.sort(reverse=True)
print(lista)
a = 0
while a < 4:
    for x in todo_el_torneo:
        if x.puntaje1 == lista[a]:
            x.puntaje2 = random.randint(10, 500)
            a = a + 1
```